# Computer reboots/freezes when using a lot of (graphics) resources

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, freeze, reboot

Whenever I would render (Cycles) using my GPUs (2x GTX 970) eventually my computer would freeze (if music was playing it would give a loud distortion pop when it happened). Then I updated my BIOS to the latest version and it stopped doing that but now it reboots when I play certain resource heavy games (Terminator Resistance in this case, for some reason Doom Eternal is not a problem).

Normally I'd think that these reboots would be a PSU issue but it's really beefy (850W and bought in the last year). My motherboard is pretty old (bought in 2012). Could that be the issue? Another option is that the main GPU (one of the GTX 970s) is no good. They're both second hand.

Another issue I had recently was that after replacing the BIOS battery the computer wouldn't boot with anything in the PCI-e slots. After upgrading the BIOS I was able to boot just fine with both GPUs.

Here's some info from CPU-Z:

```
Processors Information
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Socket 1            ID = 0
    Number of cores     4 (max 4)
    Number of threads   4 (max 4)
    Name            Intel Core i5 3570K
    Codename        Ivy Bridge
    Specification       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz
    Package (platform ID)   Socket 1155 LGA (0x1)
    CPUID           6.A.9
    Extended CPUID      6.3A
    Core Stepping       E1/L1
    Technology      22 nm
    TDP Limit       77.0 Watts
    Tjmax           105.0 °C
    Core Speed      3703.1 MHz
    Multiplier x Bus Speed  37.0 x 100.1 MHz
    Base frequency (cores)  100.1 MHz
    Base frequency (ext.)   100.1 MHz
    Stock frequency     3400 MHz
    Instructions sets   MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x, AES, AVX
    Microcode Revision  0x21
    L1 Data cache       4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L1 Instruction cache    4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L2 cache        4 x 256 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L3 cache        6 MBytes, 12-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    Max CPUID level     0000000Dh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 6 MB, 16 thread(s)
    FID/VID Control     yes


    IBRS            supported, disabled
    IBPB            supported
    STIBP           supported, disabled
    RDCL_NO         no
    IBRS_ALL        not supported
    Turbo Mode      supported, enabled
    Max non-turbo ratio 34x
    Max turbo ratio     38x
    Max efficiency ratio    16x
    Min Power       60 Watts
    O/C bins        unlimited
    Ratio 1 core        38x
    Ratio 2 cores       38x
    Ratio 3 cores       37x
    Ratio 4 cores       36x
    TDP Level       77.0 W @ 34x

    Temperature 0       58 degC (136 degF) (Package)
    Temperature 1       54 degC (129 degF) (Core #0)
    Temperature 2       56 degC (132 degF) (Core #1)
    Temperature 3       57 degC (134 degF) (Core #2)
    Temperature 4       60 degC (140 degF) (Core #3)
    Voltage 0       1.07 Volts (VID)
    Power 00        23.11 W (Package)
    Power 01        16.85 W (IA Cores)
    Power 02        n.a. (GT)
    Power 03        6.26 W (Uncore)
    Clock Speed 0       3703.11 MHz (Core #0)
    Clock Speed 1       3703.11 MHz (Core #1)
    Clock Speed 2       3703.11 MHz (Core #2)
    Clock Speed 3       3603.03 MHz (Core #3)
    Core 0 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)
    Core 1 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)
    Core 2 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)
    Core 3 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)Processors Information
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Socket 1            ID = 0
    Number of cores     4 (max 4)
    Number of threads   4 (max 4)
    Name            Intel Core i5 3570K
    Codename        Ivy Bridge
    Specification       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz
    Package (platform ID)   Socket 1155 LGA (0x1)
    CPUID           6.A.9
    Extended CPUID      6.3A
    Core Stepping       E1/L1
    Technology      22 nm
    TDP Limit       77.0 Watts
    Tjmax           105.0 °C
    Core Speed      3703.1 MHz
    Multiplier x Bus Speed  37.0 x 100.1 MHz
    Base frequency (cores)  100.1 MHz
    Base frequency (ext.)   100.1 MHz
    Stock frequency     3400 MHz
    Instructions sets   MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x, AES, AVX
    Microcode Revision  0x21
    L1 Data cache       4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L1 Instruction cache    4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L2 cache        4 x 256 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L3 cache        6 MBytes, 12-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    Max CPUID level     0000000Dh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 6 MB, 16 thread(s)
    FID/VID Control     yes


    IBRS            supported, disabled
    IBPB            supported
    STIBP           supported, disabled
    RDCL_NO         no
    IBRS_ALL        not supported
    Turbo Mode      supported, enabled
    Max non-turbo ratio 34x
    Max turbo ratio     38x
    Max efficiency ratio    16x
    Min Power       60 Watts
    O/C bins        unlimited
    Ratio 1 core        38x
    Ratio 2 cores       38x
    Ratio 3 cores       37x
    Ratio 4 cores       36x
    TDP Level       77.0 W @ 34x

    Temperature 0       58 degC (136 degF) (Package)
    Temperature 1       54 degC (129 degF) (Core #0)
    Temperature 2       56 degC (132 degF) (Core #1)
    Temperature 3       57 degC (134 degF) (Core #2)
    Temperature 4       60 degC (140 degF) (Core #3)
    Voltage 0       1.07 Volts (VID)
    Power 00        23.11 W (Package)
    Power 01        16.85 W (IA Cores)
    Power 02        n.a. (GT)
    Power 03        6.26 W (Uncore)
    Clock Speed 0       3703.11 MHz (Core #0)
    Clock Speed 1       3703.11 MHz (Core #1)
    Clock Speed 2       3703.11 MHz (Core #2)
    Clock Speed 3       3603.03 MHz (Core #3)
    Core 0 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)
    Core 1 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)
    Core 2 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)
    Core 3 max ratio    38.0 (effective 38.0)

Chipset
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Northbridge         Intel Ivy Bridge rev. 09
Southbridge         Intel Z77 rev. 04
Graphic Interface       PCI-Express
PCI-E Link Width        x16
PCI-E Max Link Width        x16
Memory Type         DDR3
Memory Size         8 GBytes
Channels            Single
Memory Frequency        800.7 MHz (1:6)
CAS# latency (CL)       11.0
RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD)   11
RAS# Precharge (tRP)        11
Cycle Time (tRAS)       30
Command Rate (CR)       1T
Host Bridge         0x0150

Mainboard Model     Z77M-D3H (0x00000201 - 0x00B6E5F6)

Display Adapters
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Display adapter 0   
    ID          0x1080204
    Name            NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
    Board Manufacturer  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. (MSI)
    Revision        A1
    Codename        GM204
    Technology      28 nm
    Memory size     4 GB
    Memory type     GDDR5
    PCI device      bus 1 (0x1), device 0 (0x0), function 0 (0x0)
    Vendor ID       0x10DE (0x1462)
    Model ID        0x13C2 (0x3160)
    Revision ID     0xA1
    Performance Level   0
        Core clock  135.0 MHz
        Memory clock    324.0 MHz

Display adapter 1   
    ID          0x1080204
    Name            NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
    Board Manufacturer  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. (MSI)
    Revision        A1
    Codename        GM204
    Technology      28 nm
    Memory size     4 GB
    Memory type     GDDR5
    PCI device      bus 2 (0x2), device 0 (0x0), function 0 (0x0)
    Vendor ID       0x10DE (0x1462)
    Model ID        0x13C2 (0x3160)
    Revision ID     0xA1
    Performance Level   0
        Core clock  135.0 MHz
        Memory clock    324.0 MHz

Win32_VideoController       AdapterRAM = 0xFFF00000 (4293918720)
Win32_VideoController       AdapterRAM = 0xFFF00000 (4293918720)
Win32_VideoController       DriverVersion = 26.21.14.4587
Win32_VideoController       DriverVersion = 26.21.14.4587
Win32_VideoController       DriverDate = 04/03/2020
Win32_VideoController       DriverDate = 04/03/2020
```

Comment: Add up the full description of your build on your question. Did you already check out if there are messages in any drive on the [Device Manager](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/7-ways-to-access-device-manager-in-windows-10.html)?

Comment: Are you running them in SLI? That is notorious for causing issues. Are you running them with an SLI bridge? I know this might be a silly question, but have you checked that all your drivers are up to date?

Comment: I'm not running the GPUs in SLI. Non of my drives seem to be having any issues.

What information are you missing? I'm worried that if I paste the whole thing I might end up posting privacy/security sensitive info.